# Awk:How to get a part of a field?

Tags: awk

I got this data:

```
aaa:123 bbb:**234** ccc:345

eee:435 ddd:**231** xxx:897

...
```

How to get the bolded part by using Awk?

Comment: I solve this problem by using `substr` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression of spaces plus colon and count fields:

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]:]+' '{ print $4 }' infile
```

It yields:

```
234
231
```

Answer (score 16):

A general approach to obtaining portions of fields is to use `split`:

```
awk -F':' '{ split($3, subfield, " "); print subfield[1] }'
```

Others have mentioned using a regex to treat both spaces and colons as field separators. This is fine, so long as the number of spaces is predictable. But it will fail otherwise, e.g., for input like this:

```
aaa:123 bbb:234 ccc:345
eee:435 ddd:231 xxx:897
fff:214 ads 23423 fds:183 eee:234
```

Pick whichever approach better matches your data.

Comment: All solution assume some formatting, what if one line does contain `fff:214 ads:23423 fds:183 eee:234` and he like `183` from this line. It will only be speculation.

Comment: @Jotne I fail to see your point. Yes, a format is needed, that's trivial. Yes, the data format is ambiguous, so there's speculation in all answers. So what? Why do you think that makes an arbitrary assumption about which field is desired of any interest?

Comment: I do assume as much as you do, it was just an comment.  Its always good that the OP post as much data as possible.

Comment: @Jotne So just trying to reinforce the point that the strategy needs to match the data? OK. Then I'll leave my answer unchanged.

Comment: I think the keyword should be "subfields" and not "subfield"

ref: [http://www.bolthole.com/awk5.html](http://www.bolthole.com/awk5.html)

Answer (score 4):

I would have used this:

```
awk '{split($2,a,":");print a[2]}' file
```

Why? Its not easy to see if its space or tab that separates the filed. Using default setting of FS in awk is any blank, so it will work even if its tab or spaces. Then we from second field take out part we need, using split by `:`

Answer (score 3):

It's rather straightforward.  Did you try

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{print $4}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
BEGIN { FS = ":" }
{  
   split($(NF-1),a," ");
   $2=a[2]; 
   print $2;   
}
```

Supposed that your column is is always the `2th` and the number of columns is `3`.

Comment: This returns '123 bbb' and '435 ddd', not what the OP asked for.